# Tabela de distâncias google maps api e python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, csv

Olá,

Eu estou utilizando a API do Google Maps para verificar a distancia entre dois pontos, para isso, tenho dois arquivos locais.csv e coordenacoes.csv.

O objetivo final é saber a distancia dos locais para cada uma das coordenações.

Se existirem 3 locais e 2 coordenações, o resultado esperado era para ser:

```
Local1, Coordenacao1
Local1, Coordenacao2
Local2, Coordenacao1
Local2, Coordenacao2
Local3, Coordenacao1
Local3, Coordenacao2
```

Mas o codigo abaixo está retornando somente o primeiro item da coordenação:

```
Local1, Coordenacao1
Local1, Coordenacao2
```

Acredito que o erro esteja na utilização do **for**

```
import googlemaps
import csv

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='TOKEN')

coluna_participante = 0
coluna_coordenacao = 0

entrada_local = open('arquivos/locais.csv', 'r')
entrada_coordenacao = open('arquivos/coordenacoes.csv', 'r')
saida = open('arquivos/saida.csv', 'w', newline='')

try:
    ler_local = csv.reader(entrada_local)
    ler_coordenacao = csv.reader(entrada_coordenacao)
    escrever = csv.writer(saida)
    for row in list(ler_coordenacao)[1:]:
        coordenadas_coordenacao = row[coluna_coordenacao]
        for row in list(ler_local)[1:]:
            coordenadas_local = row[coluna_local]
            distancia = gmaps.distance_matrix(coordenadas_local, coordenadas_coordenacao)
            print(distancia)

finally:
    entrada_local.close()
    entrada_coordenacao.close()
    saida.close()
```

Também gostaria de obter o resultado em formato de tabela, no arquivo saida.csv no seguinte modelo:

```
local1, distancia(1,1), distancia(1,2)
local2, distancia(2,1), distancia(2,2)
local3, distancia(3,1), distancia(1,2)
```

Quais alterações eu devo realizar?

Comment: A resolução pode ser consultada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702740/table-of-distances-with-python-and-google-maps-api